# Contact electricity and photoelectric effect

Tags: electricity, photons, physical-constants, photoelectric-effect, solar-cells

Most universities provide an experiment about the photoelectric effect to determine $h$ by measuring the stop voltage against the light frequency and calculating the slope $h/e$.

But mostly they also talk about the contact voltage, which just changes the offset, but not the slope.

I have several related questions regarding this contact voltage in combination with the photoelectric effect:

- Why do they talk about contact voltages at all if it's irrelevant for the slope?
- Why are the photo cells build with two different materials at all? The same material would give no contact voltage and everything would be fine.
- Books and Wikipedia tell me contact voltage is the voltage between two materials that are connected *directly*. But the photo cell's electrodes are not contacted directly, but normaly through copper cables and with several devices inbetween. Doesn't this change the contact voltage inpredictable?
- Are there papers or books or something that explains contact electricity from ground up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- They talk about contact voltages because it affects “stop voltage” as measured by their instruments, but it doesn’t affect $\Delta U_{\rm stop} / \Delta\nu$ since aforementioned contact voltages are assumed independent of illumination conditions.
- Because a photovoltaic cell made of a homogeneous piece of material won’t work. A piece of conductor will not produce any voltage, whereas you will be unable to extract the current from a dielectric.
- No, it doesn’t. You can also read an interesting discussion at [Ambiguity on the notion of potential in electrical circuits?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/129404/ambiguity-on-the-notion-of-potential-in-electrical-circuits). BTW, where does Wikipedia tell you about the *contact voltage*? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volta_potential , or… ? A posting that vaguely refers to “books and Wikipedia” without any specificity demonstrates a shortage in Internet communication skills, especially given that the people refers to *several* different things as to contact voltages.
- I don’t known (I’m not an English speaker, usually).